# angularjs onsen-ui sliding-menu div mouse doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arcadio_ortega/54fpzzpd/)

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div contenteditable="true" style="line-height: 90%; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #0000FF; padding: 10px; width: 96%; min-height: 70px;" >
</body>
```

it works

but if I add sliding-menu doesn't work:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arcadio_ortega/6e2sc1xt/)

```
<body ng-app="app">
<ons-sliding-menu
    menu-page="menu.html" main-page="hola.html" side="left"
  </ons-sliding-menu>
    <ons-template id="hola.html">
      <div contenteditable="true" style="line-height: 90%; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #0000FF; padding: 10px; width: 96%; min-height: 70px;" >
                                </div>
  </ons-template>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When using jsfiddle, please also post the code.  I've done it for you this time.  (in edit review queue)

Comment: Thank you @rrauenza

Comment: I found the issue but not the solution. in `Onsen CSS`  they have disabled the `user-select` thats why you cant even yous elect the text. I think there are some more css which they have added to block user interaction.

Comment: Where is your menu.html template?

Comment: it's not necessary... the problem is the same....I just wanted to simplify the code

Comment: I was just seeing what else you were doing that might have impacted the rest of your code.  Regardless, I have posted your code working in an answer below.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code pen for the sliding menu with your code - it blocks user input and I am not positive why they did that, but the css override functions in chrome at least.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLxPOa  In general, you should have your code wrapped in `ons-page`.

Additionally, I think sliding menu has been relegated to Angular 1 bindings only and recommend using `ons-splitter`. It is the same functionality with more options though and most importantly, no CSS hacks to make it work.

Here is a functioning codepen that shows your div working but uses splitter instead:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNbgZR?editors=101

```
<ons-splitter>
  <ons-splitter-side id="menu" side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
    <ons-page>
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('home.html')" tappable>
          Home
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('settings.html')" tappable>
          Settings
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('about.html')" tappable>
          About
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-splitter-side>
  <ons-splitter-content id="content" page="home.html"></ons-splitter-content>
</ons-splitter>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
          <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Main
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div contenteditable="true" style="line-height: 90%; border-radius: 25px; border: 2px solid #0000FF; padding: 10px; width: 96%; min-height: 70px;" >
        </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
My example works on the candidate onsen-iu 2.0 version but I do not want to upgrade until the final version is published.
I guess that I will adopt your solution (ons-splitter) in a later version of my product but now I want to stay in the current version of onsen-iu if possible.

Comment: Well, Onsen is in their final version of 2.0 as they are working their way through RC's.  They have said they will not change the methodology by too much from here on out.  I have already published apps with the RC (6 at the time) with great success.  The UI improvements are huge and very much worth it IMO.